# facing trouble while using uimenucontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uimenucontroller

I need to use uimenucontroller in my app, where i want copy/paste/etc options, when ever i move any selected uiview/uiimageView present in uiviewcontroller.

here is the code i am using:

```
{
UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Paste" action:@selector(menuItemClicked:)];

[self becomeFirstResponder];

[menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:resetMenuItem]];
[menuController setTargetRect:imageView.frame inView:self.view];
[menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

i am calling this function in touches end in uiviewcontroller, which is pushed from rootviewcontroller, uimenucontroller is showing only at the first use of viewcontroller, when ever i go back to rootviewcontroller and pushing the uiviewcontroller , uimenucontroller is not showing menu items at touches ended.  and i can find that

```
 [self becomeFirstResponder];
```

returning NO value.. can any one help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view or view controller needs to implement -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder (returning YES)

Comment: thanks for response , But i am already using -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{ return YES; }